# changing [list]

Tags: list

Okay so I need to update the data in a list by adding a new figure at the front of the list and remove the oldest figure:

```
type Place = (String, Float, Float, [Int])

testData :: [Place]
testData = [("London", 51.5, -0.1, [0,0,5,8,8,0,0]), 
        ("Cardiff", 51.5, -3.2, [12,8,15,0,0,0,2]), 
        ("Norwich", 52.6, 1.3, [0,6,5,0,0,0,3]), 
        ("Birmingham", 52.5, -1.9, [0,2,10,7,8,2,2]), 
        ("Liverpool", 53.4, -3.0, [8,16,20,3,4,9,2]), 
        ("Hull", 53.8, -0.3, [0,6,5,0,0,0,4]),
        ("Newcastle", 55.0, -1.6, [0,0,8,3,6,7,5]), 
        ("Belfast", 54.6, -5.9, [10,18,14,0,6,5,2]), 
        ("Glasgow", 55.9, -4.3, [7,5,3,0,6,5,0]), 
        ("Plymouth", 50.4, -4.1, [4,9,0,0,0,6,5]),
        ("Aberdeen", 57.1, -2.1, [0,0,6,5,8,2,0]), 
        ("Stornoway", 58.2, -6.4, [15,6,15,0,0,4,2]),
        ("Lerwick", 60.2, -1.1, [8,10,5,5,0,0,3]), 
        ("St Helier", 49.2, -2.1, [0,0,0,0,6,10,0])]
```

I tried the below function

```
     updateRain :: Int -> Place -> Place
     updateRain x info = [info|(city,long,lat,rain)<- info, rain == newRain]
       where newRain = x : init rain

demo = zipWith updateRain [0,8,0,0,5,0,0,3,4,2,0,8,0,0] testData
```

I'm getting this error when I try to load this:

```
     Couldn't match type ‘[Place]’
                 with ‘(String, Float, Float, [Int])’
  Expected type: Place
    Actual type: [Place]
• In the expression:
    [info | (city, long, lat, rain) <- info, rain == newRain]
  In an equation for ‘updateRain’:
      updateRain x info
        = [info | (city, long, lat, rain) <- info, rain == newRain]
        where
            newRain = x : init rain
   |
43 | updateRain x info = [info|(city,long,lat,rain)<- info, rain == newRain]
```

Anyone know where I'm going wrong? I want the parameters taken in to be the new data and the testData and the output to be the testData with the rain being updated to the new figure at the head and removing the last figure in each list.

Comment: `updateRain x info = [info|(city,long,lat,rain)<- info, rain == newRain]` will not work, since that expects `info` to be a *list* of `Place`s.

Comment: Hi, so would taking the square brackets out resolve this? I want to be able to express to the function that rain needs to be newRain in the lists within testData when the final function is called

Comment: The square brackets are list comprehension, so that means `info` should be a list here. But just leaving out the square brackets will not fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `updateRain` function uses list comprehension, that means that `info` in `… <- info` should be a list here, but it is just a `Place` object based on your signature.

You can use pattern matching instead:

```
updateRain :: Int -> Place -> Place
updateRain x (city,long,lat,rain) = (city, long, lat, x : init rain)
```

This can fail if `rain` is an empty list, since `init` errors on an empty list. You might want to make a separate case for that:

```
updateRain :: Int -> Place -> Place
updateRain x (city,long,lat,[]) = …
updateRain x (city,long,lat,rain@(_:_)) = (city, long, lat, x : init rain)
```

Comment: Thanks this works! I have to add  `demo :: Int -> IO ()`  but when I add this before the demo to call it and load it outputs this error: `Couldn't match expected type ‘IO ()’ with actual type ‘[Place]’` however I've tried to `print` zipWith before and it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: spacefruiticle: did you write `print (zipWith updateRain [0,8,0,0,5,0,0,3,4,2,0,8,0,0] testData)`? (so with parenthesis)?

Comment: Ah no I didn't stupid error by me completely missed that, thank you for the help this works now!

Comment: @spacefruiticle: Instead of adding another case, you can also drop from the end, which naturally handles the empty list: `dropEnd n xs = zipWith const xs (drop n xs)`, then `dropEnd 1 rain`